# Best way to send events via the internet?

Tags: java, networking

I wrote an Java Application implementing a Model View Controller structure. My View registers some listeners on the Model in order to reflect changes. Works fine.

Now I want to run Model & Controller on another PC than the View, so View is a Remote that connects to my running program. I read a lot about different ways to create APIs like REST, SOAP, RMI, just to name a few. But none of them looked like a good choice to me for my needs. As I'm sure remote Views are kinda common, is there an recommended API/way-to-go to implement Listeners-over-network`?

Comment: websockets probably?

Comment: No, remote views are actually not common since it introduces a lot of unnecessary coupling in a distributed system.